# PrepareForSegue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, nsuserdefaults

I have a NSUserDefault all set up in my viewController and this is part of it in the viewDidLoad

```
if  (txt1TotalDefault.valueForKey("TextField1Total") != nil){
            TextField1Total = txt1TotalDefault.valueForKey("TextField1Total") as! Double
            let T1Total = NSString(format: "TextField1Total: %i", TextField1Total)
    }
```

Then I have a segue at the bottom of all the code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        DestViewController.TotalMoneyLabel.text = T1Total}
```

but it will not work because it does not recognise T1Total, how would i get it to recognise it or get it out of the if statement so it can read the value correctly

Comment: `T1Total` should be class variable. In your case its method variable, because of this `T1Total` is not accessible in `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: is there a way to make the T1Total accessible in PrepareForSegue?

Comment: Is there a way to get it out of the if statement and them allow it into the segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T1Total` should be class variable. In your case its method variable, because of this `T1Total` is not accessible in `prepareForSegue` method.

## Pseudo Code

```
Class yourclass
{
    var T1Total = ""
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        if  (txt1TotalDefault.valueForKey("TextField1Total") != nil){
            TextField1Total = txt1TotalDefault.valueForKey("TextField1Total") as! Double
            T1Total = NSString(format: "TextField1Total: %i", TextField1Total)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        DestViewController.TotalMoneyLabel.text = T1Total
    }
}
```

Using this code the `T1Total` will be accessible in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Pass the text to `DestViewController` and inside `viewDidLoad()` method of `DestViewController` set the text.

Comment: so i set the viewdidload of my SecondViewController to the same text in my segue in viewController?

Comment: No, you need to set the text in `viewDidLoad` method of `SecondViewController`

Comment: can you explain have my segue in view1 and i have to set the text in SecondViewController viewdidload by doing? haveing it be TotalMoneyLabel.text = ?